# have Div fill unspecified width [IMAGES]

Tags: css, width, vaadin

This question might be more comprehensible if you have experience of Vaadin or GWT or similar, but good CSS and web development skills should be sufficient.

I'm in a dilemma. In a view in our web application we have three panels, two at the top side by side and one at the bottom that should take up as much width as the two above combined making a "square" of three panels.

*Here's an image to explain it:*

[image]

Problem is only one panel (the top left) can have a static specified width because the data displayed there is very predictable. The other one on the top right will hold differing content that could vary +-100 pixels in width.

Now I want the bottom panel to have its width adjusted and fill the same width as the panels above.

And here comes the Vaadin part (which is the framework the web application is developed in). I've tried just having the upper panels in a `HorizontalLayout` which is inside a `VerticalLayout` together with the bottom panel. I would have hoped that I could set the bottom panel to `setWidth("100%")` and it would adjust its width to how wide the `VerticalLayout` was, but of course this doesn't work since the `VerticalLayout`doesn't have a specified width.

Then I performed a test using a `GridLayout` which was 2 x 2 where the top row had two cells with layouts in each and the bottom row had the bottom layout in the two cells. *Code*:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 2);

        SHorizontalLayout h1 = new SHorizontalLayout();
        SHorizontalLayout h2 = new SHorizontalLayout();
        SHorizontalLayout h3 = new SHorizontalLayout();

        h1.addComponent(new Embedded(null, new ThemeResource("../m2m/img/lock_20x20.png")));
        h2.addComponent(new Embedded(null, new ThemeResource("../m2m/img/lock_20x20.png")));
        h3.addComponent(new Embedded(null, new ThemeResource("../m2m/img/lock_20x20.png")));

        h1.setSizeFull();
        h2.setSizeFull();
        h3.setSizeFull();

        h1.setStyleName("test-layout1");
        h2.setStyleName("test-layout2");
        h3.setStyleName("test-layout3");

        grid.addComponent(h1, 0, 0);
        grid.addComponent(h2, 1, 0);
        grid.addComponent(h3, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        outerHLayout.addComponent(grid);
```

This will give this result:

[image]

However the bottom cell has the width of the two upper combined when it's focused in the FireBug tool:

[image]

But Vaadin automatically generates a div (`<div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">`) that restricts the width of the content to the content size (even though content is set to setSizeFull()).

So I would really like to get some help with this problem in general using CSS or from someone used to Vaadin to help me with how to specify the grid so that it doesn't generate this inner cell div that restricts the width of the content.

If you need me to provide any more information then please ask me!

I know this is a tediously long question so I would really like to thank you who have read this far, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Vaadin/GWT, but in terms of CSS and HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px;"> Static width </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;display: inline-block;"> <div> dynamic width </div> </div>
    <div> dynamic width 2 </div>
</div>​
```

By default `<div>` takes up all the space, so by setting first inner `float:left;` we change the rendering flow for it, thus next div will try to take all the space left (or stretch as much as possible). `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` triggers redrawing/recalculation of those divs, so that dynamic width is correct.  The `display: inline-block;` removes miscalculations from div's width from when it is rendered in a `block` mode with margins near ("on the same line as") `floated` block.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MUN8E/3/.  Tested with Chrome, IE9. (Seems not to work with IE7, tell me if IE7 support is required)

**Modified stucture**

```
<div style="overflow: auto;float: left;">
  <div>        
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px;"> static</div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;display: inline-block;">
        dynamic width
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     dynamic width 2
  </div>
</div>​
```

Which has the same structure as in **@Marthin**'s answer.
If container `div` is not `floated` it will take all the space.

I am not sure whether you can do it that way in Vaadin, but based on **@Marthin** answer, you could do something like this (using same structure):

```
container.setStyleName("container");
smallTopLeft.setWidth("300px"); 
smallTopLeft.setStyleName("small_left"); //
smallTopRight.setStyleName("small_right");
```

And CSS styles:

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
}
.container div {
    float: none;
    display: block; /* In case css produced by Vaadin has floats by default */
}
.small_left {
    float: left;
}
.small_right {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer relic! I'm not at work now so I'll have to wait until Sunday until I can try and apply this to my CSS. However, I read you don't have experience from using Java framework tools for generating web code, and one thing that's a problem is that the HTML you provided is far from the reality in the existing markup. The HTML is auto generated from Java and there are many barriers to pass to get CSS properties to be applied in the intended way. I'll post the markup when I get back, I would assume that it's built out of maybe 40-50 tags rather than the 4 presented here.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you let your 3 views get added in a main container that is a VerticalLayout and that your two smaller top layouts get wrapped within a horozontallayout that in turn also gets added to the main container.

Somehitng like this

```
    VerticalLayout container = new VerticalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout topWrapper = new HorizontalLayout();

    container.setSizeFull();
    topWrapper.setSizeFull();

    VerticalLayout smallTopLeft = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout smallTopRight = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout largeBottom = new VerticalLayout();

    smallTopLeft.setWidth("300px");
    smallTopRight.setSizeFull();
    largeBottom.setSizeFull();

    topWrapper.addComponent(smallTopLeft)
    topWrapper.addComponent(smallTopRight)

    container.addComponent(topWrapper);
    container.addComponent(largeBottom);
```

Comment: Thank you Marthin! Actually that's pretty much as I had done it, except I don't have container.setSizeFull() because that would stretch it across the screen which would cause a lot of excessive space in the panels. I would want the lower panel to have its width governed by the width of the container which in turn would have its width governed by the two upper panels. So that the two rows of panels take up the same width as the image describes. You have any idea of how to do this without setting the width of the container?